# How can I fix/disable the slow image slider on my WooCommerce product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently experiencing an issue with the image slider on my WordPress product page. When I access the site from my phone, the slider transition between images is very slow, and it takes a few seconds for the next image to load.

To improve the user experience and make the slider transition immediate, I would like to disable the sliding effect and set the transition to 0s. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this in WordPress.

I've already tried implementing the CSS code provided by [site](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-disable-zoom-gallery-slider-lightbox-single-product/), as well as modifying the translate3d property, but the slider still moves very slowly between images.

I'm using the Astra theme and WooCommerce plugin for my site. Could anyone please guide me on how to disable the slider effect?

Thank you in advance for your help.
[this is my site](https://xversi.com/product/%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99-original-2/)